# Rewriting URLS with traling slash, parameters etc

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm having trouble with htaccess.

Here are my requirements:

> 1) pages/PAGE (no trailing slashes) ## page.php?page=PAGE
>
> 2) pages/PAGE/DATA (no trailing slashes) ## page.php?page=PAGE&data=DATA
>
> 3) login, logout, index (no .php or /)
>
> 4) pages (with or without slash) to redirect to login (no slash or .php)

This is what I have currently tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^logout$ pages/logout.php [NC,L]

#1 
RewriteRule ^pages/(\w+)$ page.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
#2
RewriteRule ^pages/(\w+)/(\w+)$ page.php?page=$1&data=$2 [NC,L]

#3
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)/$ $1
```

The problem with this is that the root gives me 'Redirect loop' 
Pages (with or without trailing /) gives me a redirect loop

Answer (score 0):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^logout$ pages/logout.php [NC,L]

#1 
RewriteRule ^pages/(\w+)$ page.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
#2
RewriteRule ^pages/(\w+)/(\w+)$ page.php?page=$1&data=$2 [NC,L]

#3
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```